# Jsmooth icon looks bad

Tags: jar, icons, jsmooth

I'm converting an executable jar to an exe with JSmooth. I'm setting an Icon in png for the application. It loads and it's show OK at Jsmooth. Then I convert to exe, and it works, but the icon looks very bad, pixelated.

My icon is a 64x64 png with transparent background. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Jsmooth autoscale to 32x32 and reduce colors to 256, so it's preferable to do that with external software, or give Jsmooth a proper ico file.

Extracted from [Jsmooth user manual](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html):